# I want to copy files from File System to another FileSystem based on Country wise Tried with GetMetadata but ingesting only one file in the target

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Files are in the form of Country wise in the FileSystem want to copy files as is in another Source System and then I need to copy them into adls So basically I need to use copy data twise if any code Suggestions that would be great Thank you in Advance
ex:
AU==>Filename1.csv
Filename2.csv
Filename3.csv
UK==>Filename1.csv
Filename2.csv
EU==>Filename1.csv
Filename2.csv
source path

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/55u82.png]

target should be same but identically I need to copy in two locations by using single PL

Comment: Can you provide your source folder structure and expected target folder structure?

Comment: Edited Question have a look once

Comment: Is the picture your expected target folder structure? Correct me if I am wrong, you have files which have names like `AU`,`UK`,`EU` in the file names in source folder and your target folder should have the files with their respected named country folders?

Comment: Exactly there were 9 countries and each country have 8 files and 2 target structures is also same as Source structure

Comment: Asking for a better understanding of the requirement. So, all your source files have a country name in it? and all are in a single source folder? Coming to target folder, the country folders should be generated from file names and those folders should have the respective files in it, right?

Comment: Source folderstructure is Campaigndata/<9 countrynames>/<files> No need to fetch countrynames from file name source is shown above picture as is we need to ingest

Comment: If the above picture is your source then can you give your expected target folder structure?

Comment: same as is i need to copy files in the same format but targets are two locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Preserve Hierarchy** in the Copy behavior of copy activity to achieve your requirement.
This takes the files from source directory and preserves the same hierarchy in the target.
As you want to copy to 2 target locations, you need to use 2 copy activities.

I have taken my source File structure as same as yours.
First create a source delimited dataset and give the path only till Root container.

Give this to copy activity and use wild card path in it like below to get your all files.

[image]

For sink, create another delimited dataset. Here for giving two target container names, use dataset parameter like below.

[image]

In copy activity sink, give your first target container name and select **Preserve Hierarchy**.

[image]

Create another copy activity like above. You can use Clone option for this.

In this, give second target container name.

[image]

Execute this and you can get the desired result.

**Target 1:**

[image]

**Target2:**

[image]